# Is there a limit to the number you can transfer back for candy?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokemon Go I have come to a point where it no longer lets me transfer pokemon back for candy. Is there a limit to the number you can transfer?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Do you have a strong connection? I suspect this is a glitch, since if you can't transfer Pokemon there's no way to remove unwanted Pokemon from your collection, which means eventually you won't be able to catch any more.

Comment: I assume you think you can't transfer it because the button is no longer there? Click the circle at the bottom right and you can transfer from there.

Comment: Can you elaborate details like, errors, missing options?

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to the number you can transfer to the Professor. I know people who have transferred over three hundred Pidgeys, and got candy for each one of them.

If you're actually transferring Pokemon back to the Professor but aren't getting any candy, it's likely a glitch -- check a Pokemon in the same family. Their candy could will have increased. If not, contact Niantic.

If you don't see the Transfer button at all as of the latest update, it was moved into the action menu (the bottom right-hand circle).